# CSS: Pop-up is hiding another control

Tags: jquery, css, vb.net

I am trying to bring my pop-up in-front of another control(auto-complete text box) but is displaying behind the text box control.

```
                <div id="navTarget">
                    <ul class="menuTarget">
                        <li><a href="#">&nbsp;</a>
                            <ul style="cursor: pointer;">
                                <asp:Literal ID="litQuickSearchTarget" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>

#navTarget .menuTarget li ul {
background: #fcecdd ;  
width: 150px; 
margin: 0; 
padding: 0; 
position: absolute; 
top: -9999px; 
left: 0;  
box-shadow: 0px 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.40);
 -moz-box-shadow: 0px 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.40); 
 z-index: 2000;
 -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.40);}
```

Comment: Sounds like a z-index issue. Make sure the element you want to appear at the front has a higher z-index.

Answer (score 1):

You have to play with the z-index :

```
#navTarget .menuTarget li ul {
background: #fcecdd ;  
width: 150px; 
margin: 0; 
padding: 0; 
position: absolute; 
top: -9999px; 
left: 0;  
z-index:10; //the bigger is always in front
box-shadow: 0px 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.40);
 -moz-box-shadow: 0px 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.40); 
 z-index: 2000;
 -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.40);
}
```

Comment: I already tried with z-index by putting smaller and bigger numbers. In my code, I put '2000' for z-index.

Comment: Try to take a look at the z-index of the autocomplete. If it's come from a plugin, the css of the autocomplete might have a greater z-index.